# How to get customer informations inside Rest API

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, api

How can I get the customer informations using the Api.php?

I tried to use exactly how I use in another parts of the code but it apparently don't work at the same way (the part that I tried to change has a comment above):

`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php`

```
public function info($orderIncrementId)
{
    $order = $this->_initOrder($orderIncrementId);

    if ($order->getGiftMessageId() > 0) {
        $order->setGiftMessage(
            Mage::getSingleton('giftmessage/message')->load($order->getGiftMessageId())->getMessage()
        );
    }

    $result = $this->_getAttributes($order, 'order');

    $result['shipping_address'] = $this->_getAttributes($order->getShippingAddress(), 'order_address');
    $result['billing_address']  = $this->_getAttributes($order->getBillingAddress(), 'order_address');
    $result['items'] = array();

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getGiftMessageId() > 0) {
            $item->setGiftMessage(
                Mage::getSingleton('giftmessage/message')->load($item->getGiftMessageId())->getMessage()
            );
        }

        $result['items'][] = $this->_getAttributes($item, 'order_item');
    }

    $result['payment'] = $this->_getAttributes($order->getPayment(), 'order_payment');

    $result['status_history'] = array();

    foreach ($order->getAllStatusHistory() as $history) {
        $result['status_history'][] = $this->_getAttributes($history, 'order_status_history');
    }

    //THIS IS THE PART THAT I TRIED TO CHANGE:

    $customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

    $result['customer_taxvat'] = $this->_getAttributes($customer->getCustomAttribute(), 'custom_attribute');

    //

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the bolow code.

```
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId($this->_getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    $customer->getCollection() ->addFieldToFilter('email', $order->getCustomerEmail())->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: I need to use a custom attribute.. like `custom_attribute` for example

Comment: use that "custm_attribute"  field instead of  "email "

Comment: I tried:
        `$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId($this->_getStore()->getWebsiteId());

        $result['customer_taxvat'] = $customer->getCollection() ->addFieldToFilter('cnpj', $order->getCustomerCnpj())->getFirstItem();

        return $result;` for attribute `cnpj`, didn't worked :(

Comment: is that worked for email?